# Numato Ethernet Relay Module telnet in c#

Tags: c#, module, telnet, ethernet, relayjs

I'm creating a windows desktop app (c#) and trying to send telnet command to toggle switch on/off ethernet relay when clicking the "ON" button. the problem is that when I click the button nothing happens.

*IP : 192.168.1.1

UN : samp

PW : samp*

`string command = "relay on 1";`

`client.Send(Encoding.GetEncoding(command).GetBytes("u" + '\n'));`

I ready try the code above but nothing happens.

This is the original java code I want to convert to C#.

```
 String relayNumber = "2"; //Change the Relay Number here when required
            byte[] data = new byte[256];
            data = new byte[256];
            data = (new String("relay off " + relayNumber + "\r\n")).getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Info: Command sent to relay on " + relayNumber);
            outstr.write(data, 0, data.length);
```

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is very probably your Router, not the device you are aiming for.

Comment: Also, this line does not really make sense: `client.Send(Encoding.GetEncoding(command).GetBytes("u" + '\n'));`  That would send a "u\n" but before that I would expect `GetEncoding` to throw an exception. Please post a little more context of that code.

Comment: ^^ I'd expect an `ArgumentException`, because "relay on 1" is _"not a valid code page name._" nor is it _"supported by the underlying platform"_. => [GetEncoding(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=net-7.0#system-text-encoding-getencoding(system-string))

Comment: sorry for incomplete information I already updated the question above. what I want the outcome is that i want to send telnet command to turn on/off the relay.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the device can take utf8? Also, the Java code is assigning `data` 3 times. That's 2 too many :D ... but all that probably won't fix your problem. Again: I am highly suspicious about that IP Adress.

Comment: I am also missing the port you are using ...

Comment: Honestly: Whoever gave you that code - I wouldn't trust them too much.

Comment: Please add what type of client you are using and how you set it up. Then I can maybe amend the answer with something _actually_ helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a UTF-8 encoded command string of the form

> relay {on|off} {relayNumber}

You can use something like:

```
public static byte[] GetRelayCommandBytes(bool onoff, int relayNumber) 
{
     return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"relay {(onoff?"on":"off")} {relayNumber}");
}
```

---

I am still suspicious about the IP Adress you mentioned in the question. `192.168.1.1` is a somewhat common one for a Router.

---

Another source of error may be the type of client you are using and how it is set up. By the time of writing this information is not in the question, unfortunately.

---

I really do not want to disrespect, but whoever gave you that code may rethink his life choices:

```
String relayNumber = "2"; //Change the Relay Number here when required
byte[] data = new byte[256]; // <- 1. declaration and assignment of array.
data = new byte[256]; // <- 2. assignment of array!! Why??
// vv- 3. assignment, making the prior 2 completely senseless.
data = (new String("relay off " + relayNumber + "\r\n")).getBytes("UTF-8");
//      ^- my Java is rusty, but I am pretty confident, `new String` is not the best of ideas.
System.out.println("Info: Command sent to relay on " + relayNumber);
// => "Logging" successful transmission, when it didn't even write, yet.
outstr.write(data, 0, data.length);
```

I am just dissecting this for you, so you can make your own informed decision about whether you may want to do your own research on how to speak to the device instead of relying on code of that "quality" as a template.

Comment: the code is from numato lab website itself https://numato.com/product/16-channel-ethernet-relay-module/ . I have ethernet relay module from numato lab and I want to control the switch through telnet but they only have java code so I want to convert it to c# .

Comment: my bad the IP address of the device is 192.168.1.4,

Comment: This is from a company website? Holy semiconductor!

Comment: yes sir! , can you recommend something to easily toggle switch on/off the ethernet relay module using c# desktop app?

Comment: Well, if telnet is their chosen method of interfacing, then it's that.

Comment: I think telnet is way to go, this really new to me since its my first time developing an app interacting with ethernet relay, my problem is that I'm not familiar on how to send telnet command to this specific device.